# How to use like query with joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following tables
tax_first

```
id      file_id     column_id       text
1       10          1               night
2       10          1               night
```

tax_second

```
id      file_id     text
1       10          night
2       10          night of the day
3       10          night of the day
```

I want to fetch all data where "text"(night) contain any of the word(night of the day),But right now only displaying,data related with "night" not "night of the day",Here is my current query

```
SELECT ts.*,tf.* 
FROM tax_second ts 
JOIN `tax_first` `tf` 
ON `ts`.`text` = `tf`.`text` 
WHERE ts.text Like '%night%'
```

Comment: The join condition `ts.text = tf.text` will only be true for one tex_second row. Are you sure you have the right join columns?

Comment: Agree with @jarlh the join is going to only isolate night because in your leading table you only have night.  You could either join on a different column like id or file id (if that makes sense with your data) or add a function to tf.text to look for wild card night searches.